# Concatenate lists of strings by day in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

documents = [['Human', 'machine', 'interface'],
             ['A', 'survey', 'of', 'user'],
             ['The', 'EPS', 'user'],
             ['System', 'and', 'human'],
             ['Relation', 'of', 'user'],
             ['The', 'generation'],
             ['The', 'intersection'],
             ['Graph', 'minors'],
             ['Graph', 'minors', 'a']]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.array(['2014-05-01', '2014-05-02', '2014-05-10', '2014-05-10', '2014-05-15', '2014-05-15', '2014-05-20', '2014-05-20', '2014-05-20'], dtype=np.datetime64), 'text': documents})
```

There are only 5 unique days. I would like to group by day to end up with the following:

```
documents2 = [['Human', 'machine', 'interface'],
              ['A', 'survey', 'of', 'user'],
              ['The', 'EPS', 'user', 'System', 'and', 'human'],
              ['Relation', 'of', 'user', 'The', 'generation'],
              ['The', 'intersection', 'Graph', 'minors', 'Graph', 'minors', 'a']]


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.array(['2014-05-01', '2014-05-02', '2014-05-10', '2014-05-15', '2014-05-20'], dtype=np.datetime64), 'text': documents2})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you can `aggregate` by `sum`

```
df.groupby('date').text.sum() # or .agg(sum)

date
2014-05-01                          [Human, machine, interface]
2014-05-02                                [A, survey, of, user]
2014-05-10                 [The, EPS, user, System, and, human]
2014-05-15                [Relation, of, user, The, generation]
2014-05-20    [The, intersection, Graph, minors, Graph, mino...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Or flatten your list using list comprehension, which yields same time complexity as `chain.from_iterable` but has no dependency on one more external library

```
df.groupby('date').text.agg(lambda x: [item for z in x for item in z])
```

Comment: Use with caution. This is terribly slow for larger frames (see my answer).

Answer (score 5):

`sum` has already been shown in another answer, so let me propose a solution that is a much faster (and more efficient) using `chain.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import chain
df.groupby('date').text.agg(lambda x: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)))

date
2014-05-01                          [Human, machine, interface]
2014-05-02                                [A, survey, of, user]
2014-05-10                 [The, EPS, user, System, and, human]
2014-05-15                [Relation, of, user, The, generation]
2014-05-20    [The, intersection, Graph, minors, Graph, mino...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

The problem with `sum` is that, for every two lists that are summed, a new intermediate result is created. So the operation is O(N^2). You can cut this down to linear time using chain.

---

The performance difference is apparent even with a relatively small DataFrame.

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000)  
%timeit df.groupby('date').text.sum()
%timeit df.groupby('date').text.agg('sum')
%timeit df.groupby('date').text.agg(lambda x: [item for z in x for item in z])
%timeit  df.groupby('date').text.agg(lambda x: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)))

71.8 ms ± 5.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
68.9 ms ± 2.96 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
2.67 ms ± 199 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.25 ms ± 184 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The problem will be more pronounced when the groups are larger. Particularly because `sum` is *not* vectorised for objects.

Comment: Good catch ! But I believe `.agg` would be even better than `.apply`

Comment: @RafaelC Slightly, but not by much!

Comment: Nice ;) Have added a solution with pure python , I believe the timing is similar to `agg`+`from_iterable` !

Comment: thanks man. Had already +1`d so not much more I can do , very good answer with the timings